# strange behavior of Chrome Developer Tools Console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

If you type in the console

```
> new Object()
```

Empty js object will appear in the console and it is expected, but if you type

```
> {}
```

You get `undefined`

It is strange. Doesn't it ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Calling a function with `new` always results in a value. Now, your second line,

```
{}
```

is an empty code block, not an object literal.

Try:

```
({})
```

or:

```
0,{}
```

The console parses lines you type as *statements*, not expressions.  An open curly brace at the start of a statement is a block delimiter, therefore, and not the start of an object literal. By including other tokens to force the parser into parsing an expression, you can then begin an object literal.

Comment: Hmm. Now I understood, That why in case of arrays both ways are the same (new Array() or just []). But how js interprets this construction 0,{} ?

Comment: It's an expression involving the comma operator.  There are other ways to do it too: consider `0 ? 0 : {}` or `0 || {}` or `true && {}`. The key is starting an expression unambiguously.